# Why can't 32bit binary process go beyond 4GB limit?

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, 32-bit

Have experienced `out of memory (OOM)` issues with `32bit binaries and 32 bit Perl` while attempting to load more `2-3GB of data into memory` on Linux.

Always wondered why an `OS with Demand Paging` capabilities , cannot swap out resident pages to disk and load more pages to grow beyond 4GB limitation ?

Probably there would be frequent Page-Faults happening (impacting performance) but should never hit OOM issue ?

Comment: Im not sure this should be in Stack Overflow.

Comment: They can https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527(v=vs.85).aspx https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock Just the programmer has to do the windowing manually

Comment: Paging and addressing are different. A 32-bit number has 2^32 possible values. If used as an address into some kind of memory or storage, that means that you can uniquely identify 2^32 bytes with a 32-bit pointer. If a program cannot identify more than 2^32 bytes (4GB) of memory, whatever is backing them (disk, RAM, cache, etc.), it cannot operate on them.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the 32 bit processor can only address 32 bits while accessing memory,  3 GB (3 × 10243 bytes) is the limit for this operation.

Comment: Sure , but cant OS page fault and free some addressable space by moving out out old pages to disk ?

Comment: @Shashi Page faulting is a completely different topic. The issue being discussed here is that you can't address more than 4GB of memory using 32 bits. Yes, you can page fault, but what address would you give these extra memory locations? It's like me asking you to uniquely label twenty envelopes with a single digit from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

32-Bits defines the size of the logical address space. You program can access at most 2**32 bytes of memory at any time.

If you have less than 2**32 bytes of physical memory available to a process, that is when the operating system swaps pages out to disk.

In the old days, when there was more physical memory than address space, (e.g., 16-bit address space and 1MB of memory) it was common for processors to support swapping segments of the address space in the manner that you suggest.